# C# - Make a generic foreach method that accepts any type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

Im busy updating an entity using entity framework and web api (on the PUT method of the controller). For each collection property on the updated object, I loop through and check if each item exists in the collection on the existing object or not. If not, I add it.

The trouble is I have a lot of collections on the object and I find myself repeating the following code many times over.

Is there a way for me to wrap this into a generic method and pass that method the 2 collections to compare? Maybe by specifying the name of the property to check and primary key? How would I be able to specify the type for the foreach loop for example?

```
foreach (HBGender gender in updated.HBGenders)
        {
            HBGender _gender = existing.HBGenders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.GenderID == gender.GenderID);
            if (_gender == null)
            {
                //do some stuff here like attach and add
            }
        }
return existing; //return the modified object
```

Thanks in advance. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: sure it works, a method that takes two lists and a predicate (Func<bool, T>) or something like that should work. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

In its simplest form you could write an extension method as such:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensionMethods
{
    public static ICollection<T> ForEachAndAdd<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self,
                                                  ICollection<T> other,
                                                  Func<T, T, bool> predicate) where T : class
    {
        foreach(var h1 in self) 
        {
           if(other.FirstOrDefault(h2 => predicate(h1, h2)) == null)
               other.Add(h1);
        }
        return other;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<HBGender> updated = new List<HBGender>();
List<HBGender> existing = new List<HBGender<();
return updated.ForEachAndAdd(existing, (h1, h2) => h1.Gender == h2.Gender);
```

Note that if there is extra logic needed during an add, you could add an additonal `Action<T>` parameter to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but you can play with this example:

```
List<object> a = new List<object>();
        a.Add("awgf");
        a.Add('v');
        a.Add(4);
foreach (object b in a)
        {
            Type type = b.GetType().//Select more usefull
            Convert.ChangeType(object,type);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your existing check function, as an extra parameter

```
public List<Class1> Find(List<Class1> updated, List<Class1> existing, Func<Class1, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (Class1 gender in updated)
    {
        Class1 _gender = existing.FirstOrDefault(predicate); //predicate for quoted example will be o => o.GenderID == gender.GenderID
        if (_gender == null)
        {
            //do some stuff here like attach and add
        }
    }
    return existing;
}
```